# XML file in the Raw folder doesn't connect by "openRawResourse"

Tags: java, android, opencv, haar-classifier

I'd tried to connect with `haarcascade_frontalface_alt` which locates in raw folder by this code

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt);
```

But, unfortunately, it is not working, it offers me create a new resources file in another folder, but when I do it, it is still not working
Can you help me, please.
Thank anybody, who will try to help
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeUYb.png)

Comment: Resource compilation seems to be a little flaky with recent versions of Android Studio. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? Maybe also restarting Android Studio? Or even Invalidate caches/Restart?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my computer and also Android Studio and it seems that it helps me, this problem has been solved. Thanks)